# Good approach to variable arguments on Pub/Sub implementation

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a `Pub/Sub` pattern in `C++` for a project.

I need to pass a variable number or arguments (and probably of different types) within a `trigger` call:

```
myclass.trigger("update:model", modelInstance, 10);
```

Then I should be able to access them on a callback when listening to the event:

```
myclass.on("update:model", &callback);
```

I know about `va_list` but I'm not sure it's the best choice on this scenario. Also, it needs to explicily know the first argument type in order to do `va_start`.

Maybe just accepting one argument, some kind of container, that includes everything there?

I'm looking for advices or some ideas to accomplish this.

Comment: You might want to look into [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates#C.2B.2B11), as well as [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for the callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of those C++11 features. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: What is your reason for needing to pass different arguments on different "update:model" triggers? In the observer pattern it's common to create the concept of an event and pass that to all observing objects.